# access query for repeated records that that have one criteria but not other

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have 2 tables in msaccess that one have multiple repeated records, and i want to filter this for the same field (date) but different criteria, i only want to see the records that exist in table2 and too in table1 and the date is less than some "dd/mm/yyy" but at the same time this record does not have any entry greater than the same date in the table1. something like this

```
------------SQL TABLE1 ----------- 
date            | IDkey        | user_name       | address
04/15/2015      | 111111       | Jean Gray       | 555 Bergen St.
15/04/2015      | 112233       | Homer Simposn   | 123 Main St.
10/04/2015      | 112233       | Homer Simpson   | 455 XYZ Ave. 
04/03/2015      | 123456       | Peter Griffin   | 780 111th St.
04/02/2015      | 654321       | Charles Xavier  | 555 Bergen St.
04/12/2014      | 112233       | Homer Simpson   | 123 Main St. 
04/11/2014      | 654321       | Charles Xavier  | 555 Bergen St.
04/11/2014      | 111111       | Jean Gray       | 555 Bergen St. 

------------SQL TABLE2 ----------- 
 IDkey        | user_name       | address
 112233       | Homer Simposn   | 123 Main St. 
 123456       | Peter Griffin   | 780 111th St.
 654321       | Charles Xavier  | 555 Bergen St.
 111111       | Jean Gray       | 555 Bergen St. 

SELECT table2.idkey, table1.idkey, table1.date, table1.username 
  From table1,table2 
  Where table2.idkey=table1.idkey 
    And table1.date < DateValue('01/04/2015') 
    AND table1.date IS NOT > DateValue('01/04/2015');
```

must be not repeated values in the result

the result for this query must be:

```
------------RESULT----------- 
 IDkey        | user_name       | address
 123456       | Peter Griffin   | 780 111th St.
 654321       | Charles Xavier  | 555 Bergen St.
```

Comment: pick a database. mysql, sql-server, or ms-access?

Answer (score 0):

Use NOT EXISTS, like this:

```
  SELECT table2.idkey, table1.idkey, table1.date, table1.username 
  From table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.idkey=table1.idkey 
  Where table1.date < DateValue('01/04/2015') 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.date > DateValue('01/04/2015'));
```

And use joins

Answer (score 0):

i might have syntax issues here but, try this:

```
SELECT Distint t2.IDKey, t2.user_name, t2.address 
from table2 t2
join table1 t1
on t1.IDkey = t2.IDKey
where
( t1.[date] < DateValue('01/04/2015') and  t1.[date] !> DateValue('01/04/2015'))
```